# Adding Image Caption using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an image caption to a div, the code below works fine and does what I want, however I would like to ask your advise to make the code a bit shorter :) I believe that there is a better way to do so, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div id="firstBlock" class="block"><p class="caption c1">Description</p></div>
<div id="secondBlock" class="block"><p class="caption c2">Description</p></div>
<div id="thirdBlock" class="block"><p class="caption c3">Description</p></div>
<div id="fourthBlock" class="block"><p class="caption c4">Description</p></div>
```

JQuery

```
    $("#firstBlock").hover(
        function(){
    $(".caption.c1").animate({"margin-left": "0px"});
        },
        function(){
    $(".caption.c1").animate({"margin-left": "-200px"});
        }
    );

    $("#secondBlock").hover(
        function(){
    $(".caption.c2").animate({"margin-left": "0px"});
        },
        function(){
    $(".caption.c2").animate({"margin-left": "-200px"});
        }
    );

    $("#thirdBlock").hover(
        function(){
    $(".caption.c3").animate({"margin-left": "0px"});
        },
        function(){
    $(".caption.c3").animate({"margin-left": "-200px"});
        }
    );

    $("#fourthBlock").hover(
        function(){
    $(".caption.c4").animate({"margin-left": "0px"});
        },
        function(){
    $(".caption.c4").animate({"margin-left": "-200px"});
        }
    );
```

CSS

```
.caption{
height: 150px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -200px;
margin-top: 350px;
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6e4rxev/) with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean your JavaScript code. For example:

```
$('.block').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.caption').animate({
     "margin-left": "0px"       
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.caption').animate({
     "margin-left": "-200px",
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This working code looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use separate classes. Use the common class and then find the caption.

```
$(".block").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".caption").animate({
            "margin-left": "0px"
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".caption").animate({
            "margin-left": "-200px"
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as well, the code works fine :)